# AngularJS location.path() changes URL briefly, then reverts

Tags: routes, pagination, angularjs

I'm having a frustrating morning.

I have an app that has a base location, so in the head is `<base href="/my/path/fruits/index.html" />`.  I'm trying to setup paging via a function `nextPage()`.  When I hit the link that triggers `nextPage()`, I use `$location.path('/page/:page')`.

*Expected behaviour:* The browser location url should change to `http://localhost/my/path/fruits/page/2`.

*Actual behaviour:* The browser URL changes (very briefly) to `http://localhost/my/path/fruits/page/2` and then reverts back to `http://localhost/my/path/fruits/`.

**Note**: This behaviour doesn't seem to happen if I'm not using a base location.  However, I need to use the base location because the app is sitting in a sub/sub/sub directory of the server.

**Also**: This behaviour doesn't happen if I set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)`.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug in Angular?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here are the appropriate files.

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="fruits">
  <head>
    <base href="/my/path/fruits/index.html" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCntl">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
angular.module('fruits', [], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'fruits.html',
        controller: FruitCntl,
    })
    .when('/page/:page', {
        templateUrl: 'fruits.html',
        controller: FruitCntl,
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})
    ;

    // configure html5 
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}).filter('startFrom', function() 
    {
        return function(input, start) 
        {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            if (input == undefined){
                input = [];
            }
            return input.slice(start);
        }
})
;

function MainCntl($scope,$location){
    angular.extend($scope,{
        current_page: 1,
        per_page: 3,
        fruits: [
            {name: 'Apples', color: 'red'},
            {name: 'Bananas', color: 'yellow'},
            {name: 'Oranges', color: 'orange'},
            {name: 'Grapes', color: 'purple'},
            {name: 'Blueberries', color: 'blue'},
            {name: 'Strawberries', color: 'red'},
            {name: 'Raspberries', color: 'red'},
            {name: 'Clementines', color: 'orange'},
            {name: 'Pears', color: 'green'},
            {name: 'Mangoes', color: 'orange'}
        ],

        nextPage: function(){
            this.current_page++;
            $location.path('/page/'+this.current_page);
        },

        previousPage: function(){
            this.current_page--;
            $location.path('/page/'+this.current_page);
        }
    })
    $scope.total_pages = Math.ceil($scope.fruits.length / $scope.per_page);
}

function FruitCntl($scope,$location,$routeParams){
    if ($routeParams.page != undefined){
        $scope.current_page = $routeParams.page;
    }
}
```

**fruits.html (the view)**

```
Page: <a ng-click="previousPage()" ng-show="current_page > 1">Previous</a> {{current_page}} of {{total_pages}} <a ng-click="nextPage()" ng-show="current_page < total_pages">Next</a>
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits | startFrom:(current_page - 1)*per_page | limitTo:per_page">
    {{fruit.name}} are {{fruit.color}}<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and couldn't for the life of me figure out what went wrong.
What worked for me was changing the anchor tag which had the ng-click event attached to a button tag instead. From what I can gather Angular modifies the behavior of anchor tags when no href attribute is given to prevent the default action, so this might interfere if you update the location manually in a ng-click event handler. That's only my guess though, so hopefully someone will be able to explain better.

Comment: Did you ever understand how to solve this problem? I got into your same situation. Using angular 1.0.6 or 1.1.4, doesn't change.

Comment: I am having the same problem and from what I see during URL flickering is that URL changes to `view%3Ditem123` (where item123 is my item ID added via `$location.path('/view' + item.name)`. Then it is not being picked up as a valid route and "otherwise" redirects it to root. Still have to figure out how to properly construct a path this way.

Comment: If it's too much trouble to change it to a button tag due to css styles applied to a bunch of elements you can avoid the default behaviour by deleting the href property inside that "a" tag. I had to do it this way, Cheers.

Comment: OMG!!! This has been mystifying me for weeks. Thank you VERY much for the anchor tag insight. Totally fixed the issue!

Answer (score 5):

The rollback of your browser is happening because the url change is happening two times, when the ng-click function triggers and one when the default browser behavior for an a tag happens.

So that is why you see the update in the url/view and then it goes back to the original state.

It happens this way because that is what the browser understands it should do.

### **Possible solutions:**

***Button solution***
As suggested before you can trigger the ng-click on a button, this works because the button doesn't have a meaningful href attribute that updates the url. You can add a href to the button but it won't do anything.

***a tag:***
Instead of doing the update in the ng-click avoid using a function and make the href do the logic of changing the url. It is a cleaner solution because you let the browser do the default behavior of the tag updating the url.

The benefit I see of doing it this way is that anybody can understand the url shceme at a glance, so the code is easier to maintain.

```
<a href="#/go/to/logic/5">Update to logic 5</a>
```

***a tag with ng-click:***
If you absolutely need the change to happen programmatically, what you should do is avoid the default behavior of the tag.

In jQuery you would bind to the click event and do the event.preventDefault(), and then do your custom logic.

The AngularJS way is a little bit different because of the logic separation that the framework imposes, so the way to solve this is to create a directive to do the preventDefault.

---

**IgnoreClick directive.js**

```
angularModule.directive('ignoreClick',  function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

usage example

```
<a href=”http://stackoverflow.com/” ignore-click=”ignore-click” ng-click=”whatever()”>Don't Go</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that will not be direct answer to your question on why does it work this way or is this a bug as I couldn't easily reproduce it (I mean the base path), however I will try to suggest you some solution.

You should try to use url params like ?page=4 instead of using url change to indicate which page you want to show together with *reloadOnSearch: false* param, like this:

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'fruits.html',
        controller: FruitCntl,
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})
```

I think it's enough to have only one route in your case. Now we have to change the paging logic to use search feature from $location (instead of your $location.path):

```
$location.search('page', this.current_page);
```

This way it will update your pages without creating new controller every time you change the page. Also it simplifies the routing logic. Hope that helps!

**NOTE:** I had to remove *$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');* as it breaks the site when I run it locally.